# How to use Principle Component Analysis (PCA) for dimensionality reduction in matlab

Tags: matlab, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I have 50 Matrices of data with 80*80 dimensions. I need to classify them, but before that I have to reduce the dimensionality of data. As I searched the web, the best tool is PCA. 
I know that before classification I have to transform each Matrix to row vector, But I don't know about PCA. Should I transform Matrices to row vectors and then reduce the dimensionality by PCA or no use PCA for each Matrix with its basic shape?

Comment: I couldn't find anything related to this question, Could you please give me the related links?

Comment: You don't have enough samples anyway ...   (by a factor of 128)